# ¿Por qué el comando git log me dice que mi rama actual es "Master" cuando estoy en "feature/herramienta-cli"?

Tags: git, git-commit

¿Por qué el comando git log me dice que mi rama actual es "Master" cuando estoy en "feature/herramienta-cli"?

Estoy segura que todo este tiempo he estado trabajando en la rama "feature/herramienta-cli" porque desde la parte baja de visual studio en la izquierda, logro identificar que esa es la rama en la que estoy trabajando.

La duda surge cuando intento ejecutar git log en la consola para identificar los commits de esta rama, pero el mensaje que me aparece es: tour current branch "Master" dices nota hace any commits yet.

Gracias por la información que me puedan brindar

Comment: tu rama no es local?

Comment: podrias agregar la salida de `git status` y `git branch` a la pregunta?

Comment: @L.Ronquillo esta rama ya estaba en el repositorio cuando lo clone del remoto

Comment: @eftshift0 la salida de git status es: on branch master, No commits yet. Mientras que del comando git branch no obtengo ninguna salida, simplemente me vuelve a posicionar desde la ruta desde la que ejecuto el comando

Comment: Te recomendaria colocarlo en la propia pregunta editandola.